# Load OSM data into PostgreSQL using Python script

Tags: python, postgresql, openstreetmap

I want to load OSM data into PostgreSQL database using Python script. When I am trying this Python script, it doesn't load OSM data into database. Can anyone guide me? I know how to load data in PostgreSQL using osmosis but currently I am looking for something using Python.

```
import psycopg2
from osgeo import ogr


# connect to the database
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              password="password",
                              host="localhost",
                              database="example")
# create cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trial1")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE trial1 (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, geom Geometry)")
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX trial1_index ON trial1 USING GIST(geom)")
print("Successfully created ")
connection.commit()

# define OSMfile path
osm = ogr.Open("pedestrian.osm")
layer = osm.GetLayer(1)

#  delete the existing contents of the table
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM trial1")
print(str(layer.GetFeatureCount()))
for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
    # Get feature geometry
    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    wkt = geometry.ExportToWkt()
    # Insert data into database,
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO trial1 (geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(" + "'" + wkt + "', 4326))")
    print("Data inserted successfully")
connection.commit()
```

Comment: You say it does not write the OSM data to the database. What happens instead? Have you succeeded writing e.g. a single bit of text via Python code?

Comment: first it returns 'Successfully created' for table generation .after that it writes 
-1 and Process finished with exit code 0.and the same code works for shapefile after changing the shapefile driver.

Comment: I have figure out the problem and  manage to load OSM data.so, i will upload the solution if in case it help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have figure out the problem and  manage to load OSM data.so, i will upload the solution if in case it help someone.The problem here  is for loop .Data is not going inside for loop  so i have used the special reading pattern required for interleaved reading .

```
import psycopg2
from osgeo import ogr
import gdal
import sys

connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              password="password",
                              host="localhost",
                              database="pythonosm")
# create cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trial")
cursor.execute("CREATE extension hstore")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE trial (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,tstamp Timestamp,highway text, tags hstore,geom Geometry)")
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX trial_index ON trial USING GIST(geom)")
print("Successfully created ")
connection.commit()

gdal.SetConfigOption('OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING', 'YES')
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('OSM')
# open the data source
ds = driver.Open(r"C:\Singapore.osm", 0)
if ds is None:
    print("Could not open file")
    sys.exit(1)

nLayerCount = ds.GetLayerCount()

thereIsDataInLayer = True

while thereIsDataInLayer:
    thereIsDataInLayer = False

    # read data from layers using OGR_INTERLEAVED_READING method

    for iLayer in range(nLayerCount):
        lyr = ds.GetLayer(iLayer)

        # read next Feature
        feat = lyr.GetNextFeature()
        while (feat is not None):
            # continue reading features from this layer
            thereIsDataInLayer = True
            lyr = ds.GetLayer(1)

            for feat in lyr:
            # filter highway
                highway_tag = feat.GetField("highway")
                if highway_tag == 'bridleway' or highway_tag == 'cycleway' or highway_tag == 'footway' \
                    or highway_tag == 'living_street' or highway_tag =='secondary' or highway_tag =='secondary_link'\
                    or highway_tag =='tertiary' or highway_tag =='tertiary_link' or \
                    highway_tag =='unclassified' or highway_tag =='track' or highway_tag == 'path'  \
                    or highway_tag == 'pedestrian' or highway_tag == 'residential' or highway_tag == 'road':


                    geomStand = feat.GetGeometryRef()
                    wkt = geomStand.ExportToWkt()


                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO trial(geom) values (ST_GeomFromText(" + "'" + wkt + "', 4326))")
                    connection.commit()
            feat.Destroy()
            # get the next feature
            feat = lyr.GetNextFeature()
print("done")
```

Comment: Does this work for polygon features?

Comment: I have written this code to load linestring  data into postgreSQL .But this also works for point after changing this condition  lyr = ds.GetLayer(1) to this lyr = ds.GetLayer(0).so may be it should work with polygon too .

Comment: The complex structure of the OSM data model for polygons needs some special care. They can be built from closed lines (but not always), or relations of type multipolygon, with or without inner rings. Osm2pgsql spents some computation time to achieve this. You would have to solve that in your python code.